# UITextView avoid keyboard scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have created an extension of `UIScrollView` where when a user selects a textfield and the keyboard appears, the textfield will scroll up if it is in the way of the keyboard. I have it working for a `UITextField` but it doesn't seem to work with a `UITextView`. I have searched many posts on stackoverflow but can't seem to find anything to help. Here is the code for the extension:

```
extension UIScrollView {

func respondToKeyboard() {
    self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}


func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    // Register to be notified if the keyboard is changing size i.e. shown or hidden
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(_:)),
        name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil
    )
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)),
        name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil
    )
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo,
        keyboardSize = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.size {

        self.contentInset.bottom = keyboardSize.height + 15
        self.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = keyboardSize.height

        var frame = self.frame
        frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.contentInset.bottom = 0
    self.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = 0
}
```

In my view controller I would just set it like:

```
scrollView.respondToKeyboard()
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of how I can implement the `UITextView` as an extension to move up if the keyboard is in the way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the UITextView delegate methods. Check out this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_textview.htm) for more details. For swift, check the tutorial [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uitextview-uitextviewdelegate--mobile-11210).

Comment: Thanks for that link. So right now I have an extension of **UIScrollView**, should I change the extension so that it's an extension of **UITextView** and **UITextField** ?  @iOS Geek

Comment: Just thinking it might be a better way of doing it instead

Comment: @coderdojo -  You wouldn't need extension if you are handling the keyboard with delegation in your view controller.

Comment: I want to use it as an extension so that I don't repeat the same code in every view controller I have, does that make sense? @iOS Geek

Answer (score 0):

for me this solution works fine for UITextView. Perhaps u can update this for Scrollview

```
// keyboard visible??
lazy var keyboardVisible = false
// Keyboard-Height
lazy var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0

func updateTextViewSizeForKeyboardHeight(keyboardHeight: CGFloat) {
    textView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardHeight
    self.keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight
}

func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let rectValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        if  keyboardVisible == false {
            let keyboardSize = rectValue.CGRectValue().size
            keyboardVisible = true
            updateTextViewSizeForKeyboardHeight(keyboardSize.height)                
        }
    }
}

func keyboardDidHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if keyboardVisible {
        keyboardVisible = false
        updateTextViewSizeForKeyboardHeight(0)
    }
}
```